# discord.py Warns command "data is not defined"

Tags: discord.py

I have this warning command, and I tried to get it to show the warnings of the user, I tried to make the command, and it says `"data is not defined"` whenever I try and start up my bot

**Here is my code:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, user:discord.Member):
 with open("warns.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

user_data = data[str(user.id)]

print(f"Total warnings: {len(user_data)}")

for warn in user_data:
    warn_id, mod, reason, time = warn.values()
    print(f"ID: {warn_id}, mod: {mod}, reason: {reason}")
```

Comment: All of your code is outside of the function after using the context manager

Comment: @12944qwerty For the `open()` function, the contents of the file, however read, can be referenced outside of the context manager. So `data` can be referenced outside of the `with` clause, but it does still have to be referenced inside of the `async def test()` function body.

Comment: @JacobLee I know, that is what I had meant. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

As **12944qwerty** mentioned in the comments: Your code is outside the function.

*Please make sure to indent the code correctly.*

**Try your new code:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    with open("warns.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

        user_data = data[str(user.id)]
        print(f"Total warnings: {len(user_data)}")

        for warn in user_data:
            warn_id, mod, reason, time = warn.values()
            print(f"ID: {warn_id}, mod: {mod}, reason: {reason}")
```

Comment: Only the line `data = json.load(f)` has to be inside the context manager. All the other lines, even if they reference `data`, can be outside the `with` clause.

Comment: @JacobLee This would be the right way to go. All other representations give errors, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: If you decrease the indentation of the lines following and including `user_data = data[str(user.id)]` such that they are inside `async def test(...):`, but outside `with open(...) as f:`, there won't be any resulting errors. Only `data = json.load(f)` needs to be within the context manager, as opposed to the entire function body.